# Any login (openid,google etc.) which supports restricted user access?

Tags: openid, google-openid

Have been searching but cannot find any openid/google/facebook/twitter login which supports restricted user access ?

What I would like to achieve is to have a sign-on via popular social login but restrict access to a few users. I would like to achieve this without the use of a database for a static site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google/fb/twitter sign signon solutions are for consumers and are not restricted. These are open to all users of these services.
If you want to put restrictions (and don't want to maintain your own list of users on the server) then you'll need a solution that is more geared towards enterprises. 
There are also consumer solutions that can do this like Google identity toolkit, https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/
Amazon cognito https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/ 
https://auth0.com/ etc
These create and maintain accounts for you and your service needs to accept a token generated by them.